# Выгрузка информации о пользователях из Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Добрый день! Мне нужно выгрузить информацию о пользователях из Active Directory из определенного OU. Для этого я использую команду

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=test,OU=Users,OU=Moscow HQ,OU=test,DC=test,DC=local" -Properties Displayname, Telephonenumber, EmailAddress, Department, StreetAddress, Title | select Displayname, Telephonenumber, EmailAddress, Department, Title

Все бы ничего, но мне нужно вместе с этим выгрузить информацию в каких группах состоят пользователи. Для этого в эту команду можно добавить MemberOf после -Properties, но проблема в том что информация о группе выгружается полная, вот в таком виде

MemberOf : {CN=test,OU=test,OU=Общее,OU=test,OU=test,DC=test,DC=local.. .}

А мне нужно только имя. Я знаю что команда get-aduser username -property MemberOf | % {$_.MemberOf | Get-AdGroup | select Name | sort name} выгрузит только имя группы, что мне и нужно.

Но как объединить комманды Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=test,OU=Users,OU=Moscow HQ,OU=test,DC=test,DC=local" -Properties Displayname, Telephonenumber, EmailAddress, Department, StreetAddress, Title | select Displayname, Telephonenumber, EmailAddress, Department, Title и get-aduser username -property MemberOf | % {$_.MemberOf | Get-AdGroup | select Name | sort name} в одну, я понять не могу. Прошу помощи)

Comment: Вы бы оформили этот комментарий как ответ, а то в списке висит данный вопрос без ответа...

Comment: Сам спросил, сам отвечу. Это можно сделать вот так:Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=test,OU=Users,OU=Moscow HQ,OU=test,DC=test,DC=local" -Properties Displayname, Telephonenumber, EmailAddress, Department, StreetAddress, Title, MemberOf | select Displayname, Telephonenumber, EmailAddress, Department, Title, @{Name='MemberofGroup'; e={ ($_.MemberOf | Get-AdGroup | sort name | foreach {$_.name}) -join ';'} }

Comment: Не подскажите как оформить свой комментарий как ответ? Не понял как это сделать.

Comment: Под вопросом внизу страницы есть поле "Ваш ответ". Введите туда свое решение. Опубликуйте. А потом пометьте его как ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Как-то я не заметил эту кнопку) Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Такой скрипт и мне тоже пригодится :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать вот так:`Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=test,OU=Users,OU=Moscow HQ,OU=test,DC=test,DC=local" -Properties Displayname, Telephonenumber, EmailAddress, Department, StreetAddress, Title, MemberOf | select Displayname, Telephonenumber, EmailAddress, Department, Title, @{Name='MemberofGroup'; e={ ($_.MemberOf | Get-AdGroup | sort name | foreach {$_.name}) -join ';'} }`

Comment: Это всё одна строка? Может, можно разделить?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, легко - всего лишь повыносить пару строки в константы, да превратить передачу объектов через пайп в обычные вызовы.. Но судя по предыдущим сообщениям, автор похоже приниципиально не переносит многострочный код.

Comment: Просто в моем случае это единичный запрос) Ничего не мешает вам написать многострочный скрипт =)